# ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm new to OpenERP. I developed a new module to install in OpenERP v7 on ubuntu12.04 and eclipse juno, but i'm getting following error.

`"ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!"`

can any one help me...

Below is my all files.

**_*init*_.py**

```
import mymodule

__openerp__.py

{
    'name': 'mymodule',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'My own Module',
    'description': """
This is customised mymodule
""",
    'author': 'SANTOSH',
    'maintainer': 'SANTOSH',
    'images' : ['images/icon.jpg'],
    'depends': ['base','web'],
    'init_xml' : ['mymodule_menu.xml'],
    'data': [
        'mymodule_menu.xml',

    ],
    'demo': [
        'mymodule_menu.xml',
    ],
    'test': [
        'mymodule_menu.xml',
    ],

    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

**mymodule.py**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class mymodule_test(osv.osv):
    _name = "mymodule.test"
    _column = {'name':fields.char('Name',size=256, Required = True ),
               'company':fields.char('Company', size = 256, Required = True),
               }

mymodule_test()
```

**mymodule_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>


        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="mymodule.test_view_form">
            <field name="name">Mymodule</field>
            <field name="model">mymodule.test</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Mymodule" version="7.0">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="company"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>


        <record id="action_mymodule" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">mymodule</field>
            <field name="res_model">mymodule.test</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        </record>
        <menuitem id="section_main_menu" name="Mymodule" />
        <menuitem id="menuitem_id" name="MymoduleList" parent="section_main_menu" action="action_mymodule" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Can you post the error description also?

Answer (score 2):

Many mistakes in your code, syntax and logical.

1. why you write 'mymodule_menu.xml' this view in init, data, and demo
   and test, in version 7.0 init replace with data = [], and in init
   only include those file who will load at initiate time , demo are
   use for demo data, and test for testing file like yml
2. _column  use _columns you missed (s)
3. in menu creation use three layer , first super parent, parent and menu child other wise it will not be clicable.

to getting invalid xml error is because you have you missed 2. point _cloumn instead of _columns

hope this help

before going to develp first read openerp documentation in [doc.openerp.com](http://doc.openerp.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is the working module of yours. Please revert for clarification.

**_*init*_.py**

```
import mymodule
```

**_*openerp*_.py**

```
{
'name': 'mymodule',
'version': '1.0',
'category': 'Tools', # There's a procedure to add your own category  
'description': """
This is customised mymodule
""",
'author': 'Vivek',
'depends': [
    'base'
],
'data': ['mymodule_menu.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False
}
# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

**mymodule_menu.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id=" test_view_form">
        <field name="name">Mymodule</field>
        <field name="model">mymodule.test</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Mymodule" version="7.0">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="company"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>


 <!-- Module Tree View -->
    <record id="view_mymodule_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">My Module</field>
        <field name="model">mymodule.test</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="My Module">
                <field name="name" string="Name" />
                <field name="company" string="Company" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_mymodule" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">mymodule</field>
      <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">mymodule.test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form </field>
    </record>

    <!-- Top Menu Item -->
    <menuitem name="My Module" id="menu_mymodule" />

    <!-- Left-side menu: Guests -->
    <menuitem name="My Module List" parent="menu_mymodule" id="mymodule_label" />

    <!-- Action Menu -->
    <menuitem name="Actual Module List" parent="mymodule_label" id="mymodule_label_actual"
        action="action_mymodule" />
</data>
</openerp>
```

**mymodule.py**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class mymodule_test(osv.osv):
_name = "mymodule.test"
_columns = {'name':fields.char('Name',size=256, Required = True ),
           'company':fields.char('Company', size = 256, Required = True),
           }

mymodule_test()
```

You've missed many things. Please compare your code and this code to see the places you've missed.

**This is my notes on adding a new category**

How to add a new category for the developed Module?
The module category list is loaded from the file server/openerp/addons/base/module/module_data.xml.

You can also see it querying the ir_module_category Postgres table.

This is what I found:

seq name

=== ================================

1   Customer Relationship Management

2   Sales Management

3   Project Management

4   Knowledge Management

5   Warehouse Management

6   Manufacturing

7   Invoicing & Payments

8   Accounting & Finance

9   Purchase Management

10  Human Resources

11  Extra Tools

12  Marketing

13  Point of Sale

14  Advanced Reporting

And since the category id is a many2one field, no, you can't have more than one category for a module. Choose the most representative one (under which top menu will most of the menu options be?).

**To Add new Category**

In **module_data.xml**

```
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_custom_modules">
        <field name="name">Custom Modules</field>
        <field name="sequence">16</field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but my problem was simply that, writing an "openacademy" module, I had wrote in `openacademy.py`:

```
class openacademy_course(osv.osv):
    _name = 'course'
    …
```

When I should have wrote :

```
class openacademy_course(osv.osv):
    _name = 'openacademy.course'
```

So it may not help you specific case, but maybe others will find your question with the same problem.